# Displaying form data immediately on the side after submit - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

I am trying to display one piece of form data, the username, on the right side of the same page the form is present in (without page refresh).  I want this to happen as soon as I hit submit.  For this miniapp, there is no backend (not even local storage).

The following is the markup for the right-side of the page: 
The `userArray` is defined on the scope and has the usernames pushed into it.

```
    <div class="index-right">
        <p ng-repeat="user in userArray">
            {{ user }}
        </p>
    </div>
```

This is my main module and controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.validate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.userArray = [];
    console.log($scope.userArray);
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid){
        if(isValid){
            $scope.userArray.push($scope.formData.username);
        }
        console.log($scope.userArray);
    };

});
```

Currently, the usernames aren't showing up on the front page.  Although, they are being pushed into the userArray (I am consoling out the array on the browser).  Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

I am adding the whole index.html here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.2.0/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="practichemApp">
    <header class="index-header"><h1>Registration Page</h1></header>
    <hr>
    <div class="index-left" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <form id="index-form" name="practichemForm" ng-submit="submitForm(practichemForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <!-- USERNAME -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': practichemForm.username.$invalid && !practichemForm.username.$pristine }">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" required>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.username.$invalid && !practichemForm.username.$pristine" class="help-block">Username is required</p>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- EMAIL -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': practichemForm.email.$invalid && !practichemForm.email.$pristine }">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.email" required>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.email.$invalid && !practichemForm.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Please Enter a valid email.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- PASSWORD -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': practichemForm.password.$invalid && !practichemForm.password.$pristine }">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.password" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/" required>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.password.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Password needs to be at least 8 characters long.</p>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.password.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Password is too long.</p>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.password.$error.pattern" class="help-block">Password needs at least one integer, one lowercase letter and one uppercase letter.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- PASSWORD CONFIRMATION -->
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': practichemForm.passwordConfirm.$error.required && !practichemForm.passwordConfirm.$pristine }">
                <label>Password (confirmation)</label>
                <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" ng-model="formData.passwordConfirm" ui-validate="'$value == formData.password'" ui-validate-watch="'formData.password'" ng-minlength="8" ng-maxlength="20" required/>
                <p ng-show="practichemForm.passwordConfirm.$error.ui-validate && practichemForm.passwordConfirm.$dirty && practichemForm.passwordConfirm.$error.required">Passwords don't match.</p>
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="practichemForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="index-right" ng-repeat="user in userArray">
        {{ user }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is `$scope.formData.username` defined? Same with `isValid`

Comment: Where is `isValid` coming from?

Comment: `formData.username` was obtained from ng-model on the input tag.  I am assuming I cannot simply use `$scope.formData.username`.  How do I proceed?

Comment: @TheSharpieOne `isValid` is the boolean value coming from the form tag, not currently shown.

Comment: I have added the whole index.html page.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element that you want to use to show your data it outside of the scope of the place that has the data.

```
<div class="index-left" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
</div>
<div class="index-right" ng-repeat="user in userArray">
    {{ user }}
</div>
```

You can use a service to share the information, or put the `userArray` on a higher scope (like `$rootScope`, or move the ng-controller to a element that wraps both.

`$rootScope` being the easiest.. try this:

```
<div class="index-left" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    ...
</div>
<div class="index-right" ng-repeat="user in userArray">
    {{ $root.user }}
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.validate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.userArray = [];
    console.log($rootScope.userArray);
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid){
        if(isValid){
            $rootScope.userArray.push($scope.formData.username);
        }
        console.log($rootScope.userArray);
    };

});
```

Comment: Haha!  It *was* the placement of the `ng-controller` directive.  I just moved it to the body tag.  Problem solved.  However, your point about `$rootScope` is also very useful.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have your ng-repeat out of the controller scope

I created a plunker for you example (removed some fields for simplicity)

http://plnkr.co/edit/7skU1lBIU5Gy7bJ0Htgh?p=preview

Moved this inside so that it is under mainctrl's

```
   <div class="index-right" ng-repeat="user in userArray">
        {{ user }}
    </div>
```

Comment: The form is working fine.  Its data is being pushed into the userArray.  What I am trying to achieve is, render the form data on the view immediately, without any page refresh.  Now, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: if you use `ng-submit` on the form tag, it will automatically handle the submit events, be it clicking a button or hitting enter.

Comment: Ok - Now I see your question updated. in the controller try $scope.formData={};

Comment: @bhantol What is the purpose of that step?  `$scope.formData.username` is obtained from the `formData.username` input from `ng-model` on the input tag.  The `userArray` already has the usernames in it.  I am consoling out the array on the browser.  I can see the names in the array already.  Only, the `ng-repeat` is not displaying the names.

Comment: @bhantol You changed your answer after TheSharpieOne pointed out the controller scope.  Also, expanding the controller scope is as simple as cut and paste.  There was no need for a plunker example.  Smart move, brah.

Comment: i changed the anwser after your edit. i did not Sharpies answer. as i put the thing in plnkr i noticed the ngrepeat stuff being outside. no worries.